# Getting chart Google Earth Engine with a data from class group

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

i want to creat a chart from a single class group, this the code :

```
var areaImage_1990 = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(
  classified_1990)
     
    var areas_1990 = areaImage_1990.reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
          groupField: 1,
          groupName: 'class',
        }),
      geometry:geometry,
      crs: 'EPSG:32748', // WGS UTM Zona 48S
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    }); 
     
    print(areas_1990)

var list = ee.List(areas_1990.get('groups'))
var classes = list.map(function(d) {
  return ee.Dictionary(d).get('class')
})
var sums1990 = list.map(function(d) {
  return ee.Dictionary(d).get('sum')
})
var area1990_chart = sums1990.get(0);

var areaImage_2000 = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(
  classified_2000)
     
    var areas_2000 = areaImage_2000.reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
          groupField: 1,
          groupName: 'class',
        }),
      geometry:geometry,
      crs: 'EPSG:32748', // WGS UTM Zona 48S
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    }); 
     
print(areas_2000)
    
var list = ee.List(areas_2000.get('groups'))
var classes = list.map(function(d) {
  return ee.Dictionary(d).get('class')
})
var sums2000 = list.map(function(d) {
  return ee.Dictionary(d).get('sum')
})
var area2000_chart = sums2000.get(0);

var areaImage_2010 = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(
  classified_2010)
     
    var areas_2010 = areaImage_2010.reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
          groupField: 1,
          groupName: 'class',
        }),
      geometry:geometry,
      crs: 'EPSG:32748', // WGS UTM Zona 48S
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    }); 
     
    print(areas_2010)

var list = ee.List(areas_2010.get('groups'))
var classes = list.map(function(d) {
  return ee.Dictionary(d).get('class')
})
var sums2010 = list.map(function(d) {
  return ee.Dictionary(d).get('sum')
})
var area2010_chart = sums2010.get(0);

var areaImage_2020 = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(
  classified_2020)
     
    var areas_2020 = areaImage_2020.reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
          groupField: 1,
          groupName: 'class',
        }),
      geometry:geometry,
      crs: 'EPSG:32748', // WGS UTM Zona 48S
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    }); 
     
  print(areas_2020)

var list = ee.List(areas_2020.get('groups'))
var classes = list.map(function(d) {
  return ee.Dictionary(d).get('class')
})
var sums2020 = list.map(function(d) {
  return ee.Dictionary(d).get('sum')
})
var area2020_chart = sums2020.get(0);
print(area2020_chart)

//var area_stacking = areas_1990.addBands(areas_2000).addBands(areas_2010).addBands(areas_2020);
//Cartographically appropriate way to calculate area
var area_pxa = classified_1990.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()) 
                    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(),geometry,30,null,null,false,1e13)
                    .get('classification')
                   ;
 area_pxa = ee.Number(area_pxa).divide(1e4);   
 print ('Area using ee.Image.pixelArea (km²)', area_pxa);

var dataTable = [
  [
    {label: 'State', role: 'domain', type: 'string'},
    {label: 'Population', role: 'data', type: 'number'},
    {label: 'Pop. annotation', role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}
  ],
  ['1990', area1990_chart, 'a'],
  ['2000', area2000_chart, 'b'],
  ['2010', area2010_chart, 'c'],
  ['2020', area2020_chart, 'd']
];

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart = ui.Chart(dataTable).setChartType('ColumnChart').setOptions({
  title: 'Luasan Vegetasi Mangrove 1990 - 2020',
  legend: {position: 'none'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Tahun', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
  vAxis: {title: 'Luas Hektar', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
  colors: ['1d6b99']
});
print(chart);
```

But the result data chart is doesn't appear

[image]

Comment: What are your classified images here (e.g. classified_1990) ?

Comment: It has 3 class of classified in every year (Mangrove, NonMangrove, and Water) then i calculate the area of every class.. and at the end i want to create a chart from a single data class area (Mangrove) but it doensn't appear